# how to show message from global resources file in pop up window of asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am getting error using this syntax

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Test", " alert('<%=Resources.Text.Header_Login%>');");

please any suggestion reply to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Test", " alert('" + Resources.Text.Header_Login + "');");
```

Comment: If this helped you find your answer then you should click the checkmark to the left as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Test", " alert('" + Resources.Text.Header_Login + "');",true);
```

The last parameter(true) specifies that the script tags are added.